# Secure my website from fake Users (Webcam)

Tags: webrtc, webcam, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I have a website a little bit like Chatroulette and I am using WebRTC so that the users can use their webcam to communicate which each other.
How can I prevent and check if a user is using a fake webcam software like ManyCam? Is that even possible to recognize a user with a fake webcam (or virtual webcam)?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a check that is universal to hardware cameras that you can screen for when the camera is initialized?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: One could also use a simulated usb-cam wich would be undetectable even by the operating system.

Comment: you found any way ?